# Panels vs theming

Tags: theming, panels, performance, 8

Panels versus themes: What is the best way?

Since Panels is included in Drupal 8 core, isn't it the way forward? Do we still need to design static HTML pages and then integrate them with Drupal, or Panel everything out and directly place content there be it block, views or from some other modules as they are all readily available?

The issue of performance with Panels can be solved to an extent using the [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) module. We can't have all what we want; we have to compromise at something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to theme Panels properly?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64541/how-to-theme-panels-properly)

Comment: @NikhilM i have seen them but i am not asking how to theme panels properly...i am asking if panels are better way to layout and structure the site as compared to theming...thanks though for your consideration

Comment: as i said since it is included in core in drupal8 i am eager to know the answer to this

Comment: Your question is tagged `7`

Comment: sorry...edited it

Comment: As http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2192/ says we are not ready to answer Drupal 8 questions yet.

Comment: @NikhilM OK BUT what for in the case of 7? i just want to get a grisp on the issue of panels vs theming

Comment: This is a rather subjective question: There isn't a best way that is valid for everybody. If you have a specific use case, then the question could be answered. As it is, it is probably getting different answers basing on the experience users had with Panels. It is not a matter of Drupal 8 versus Drupal 7; it is a matter to ask a too broad question.

Comment: The suggested duplicated question is not a duplicated question: This question is asking if it is better to use themes or the Panels module; it doesn't ask how to theme the output of the Panels module.

Comment: This questions is to me Panels vs. Regions, and as such UI vs. Code implementation. In either case there as never been a "need" to make static HTML before theming. Theming is, in my terms, basically to add CSS to Drupal output (may it be generated or custom), which also translates to "implementing a design".

Answer (score 2):

What is in Drupal 8 is not Panels -- the Panel-ish controller is still being worked on. The SCOTCH initative was definitely Panels inspired for sure but there is no UI yet, definitely no upgrade path or anything.

However, [Spark](http://buytaert.net/spark-update-responsive-layouts-in-drupal) is based on Panels for "better forward compatibility".

Besides Spark I am sure the [Panopoly](http://drupal.org/project/panopoly) people will make sure there's an upgrade path.

With all this said, your question makes no sense. You are comparing apples to oranges. Panels vs theming, that's like asking, [Views vs custom queries](http://drupal.org/node/242311). It's for different skillsets and different situations.